# Input source icon

Tags: 14.04, unity

Two days ago I've decided to switch to Ubuntu Unity desktop after using KDE for almost six month. Everything is running smoothly with some difficulties, but I had a small problem with my input source icon, it is not showing the current language instead it is showing a black rectangle with a red ring in it. 
I tried to remove the check in the `Text Entry Settings` and re-check it again I get the same result.

Is there any way to change it.

P.S: The icon appears correctly in the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was using Kubuntu then moved back to Unity desktop, when I needed some space on my machine I uninstalled all the Kubuntu packages and problem is now solved.
It turns out that Kubuntu has some issues running alongside other desktops.